# What optimization work would you recommend to do to speed up query execution in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have tables called `ORGANIZATIONAL_STRUCTURE_HISTORY` and `SURVEYS_ORGANIZATIONS_RELATIONSHIP`. I use next version of **PostgreSQL** database:

```
PostgreSQL 11.0 (Debian 11.0-1.pgdg90+2) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit
```

Right now I use pretty simple SQL query below and the number of entries in both tables are very small. It is assumed that every week about 1 million records will be filled in the tables. I'm trying to figure out what the bottlenecks are in the request in terms of large amounts of data.

```
SELECT
    ORGANIZATIONAL_STRUCTURE_HISTORY.ORGANIZATION_ID,
    ORGANIZATIONAL_STRUCTURE_HISTORY.ORGANIZATION_NAME,
    ORGANIZATIONAL_STRUCTURE_HISTORY.ORGANIZATION_RANG,
    ORGANIZATIONAL_STRUCTURE_HISTORY.PARENT_ORGANIZATION_ID
FROM
    ORGANIZATIONAL_STRUCTURE_HISTORY
WHERE
    ORGANIZATIONAL_STRUCTURE_HISTORY.SURVEY_ID = 'bc90de33-62f9-4c6f-a7a6-6a76abb28b65'
AND 
    ORGANIZATIONAL_STRUCTURE_HISTORY.ORGANIZATION_ID IN(
    SELECT
        ORGANIZATION_ID
    FROM
        SURVEYS_ORGANIZATIONS_RELATIONSHIP
    WHERE
        SURVEY_ID = 'bc90de33-62f9-4c6f-a7a6-6a76abb28b65'
)
ORDER BY
    ORGANIZATIONAL_STRUCTURE_HISTORY.ORGANIZATION_RANG,
    ORGANIZATIONAL_STRUCTURE_HISTORY.ORGANIZATION_ID;
```

[image]

I found the old [article](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/28/why-large-in-clauses-are-problematic/) where author explain why `IN` clauses are problematic in the tables with large amount of data. Not quite sure if that's still relevant for thats why I am confused.

I change my query to next code:

```
SELECT
    ORGANIZATIONAL_STRUCTURE_HISTORY.ORGANIZATION_ID,
    ORGANIZATIONAL_STRUCTURE_HISTORY.ORGANIZATION_NAME,
    ORGANIZATIONAL_STRUCTURE_HISTORY.ORGANIZATION_RANG,
    ORGANIZATIONAL_STRUCTURE_HISTORY.PARENT_ORGANIZATION_ID
FROM
    ORGANIZATIONAL_STRUCTURE_HISTORY
JOIN SURVEYS_ORGANIZATIONS_RELATIONSHIP
    ON ORGANIZATIONAL_STRUCTURE_HISTORY.ORGANIZATION_ID = SURVEYS_ORGANIZATIONS_RELATIONSHIP.ORGANIZATION_ID
WHERE
    ORGANIZATIONAL_STRUCTURE_HISTORY.SURVEY_ID = 'bc90de33-62f9-4c6f-a7a6-6a76abb28b65'
AND
    SURVEYS_ORGANIZATIONS_RELATIONSHIP.SURVEY_ID = 'bc90de33-62f9-4c6f-a7a6-6a76abb28b65'
ORDER BY
    ORGANIZATIONAL_STRUCTURE_HISTORY.ORGANIZATION_RANG,
    ORGANIZATIONAL_STRUCTURE_HISTORY.ORGANIZATION_ID;
```

The `EXPLAIN` command for the second query return the close result.

[image]

**QUESTION**: What optimization work would you recommend to do?

Comment: Which of the two queries do you actually want to run/optimize?

Comment: I'm trying to find a quick SQL query. As you can see, both SQL requests are executed at similar times. So I have some questions. Which query is better to use in your opinion. Perhaps you can offer a better solution. What bottlenecks do you see?

Comment: If these table are of a non trivial size (e.g. more than a few thousand records), then the bigger challenge here is how to index the tables to make the queries faster.  I have address how you might do this for your second query.  Either query with indexing should be faster than either query without it.

Comment: I added an answer to cover the additions I have in mind.

Comment: Like I wrote at the beginning of my answer: the second query *could* return more result rows unless you add an expensive `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two queries are different; if you intend them to be the same, you would have to add `DISTINCT` to the second one, unless you know that there can be only one `SURVEYS_ORGANIZATIONS_RELATIONSHIP` per `ORGANIZATIONAL_STRUCTURE_HISTORY`.

I'll assume that the first query is what you really want.

You should rewrite the query; instead of

```
... WHERE a.x IN
       (SELECT y FROM b
        WHERE pred)
```

use

```
... WHERE EXISTS
       (SELECT 1 FROM b
        WHERE pred
          AND a.x = b.y)
```

These two indexes would be ideal for the query:

```
CREATE INDEX ON SURVEYS_ORGANIZATIONS_RELATIONSHIP
   (survey_id, organization_id);

CREATE INDEX ON ORGANIZATIONAL_STRUCTURE_HISTORY
   (survey_id, organization_rang, organization_id);
```

The additional assumption I am making here is that the condition on `survey_id` is selective.

Comment: Could you explain why you chose the first query? Why did he seem better to you than the other one?

Comment: They are different and may have different results. Your question seemed to suggest that the second query is intended as an optimization of the first one, so I decided to go with your original intention.

Comment: Hmmm... I agree with you that they are different queries but they return the same results. Your last comment little bit confused me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Finally I decided to use your advice. The cost of the query with `EXISTS` is less than `IN`.

Answer (score 2):

For the second query, here are two indexing strategies you may consider.  First, here is a strategy would be used assuming Postgres decides to scan the `ORGANIZATIONAL_STRUCTURE_HISTORY` table first:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON SURVEYS_ORGANIZATIONS_RELATIONSHIP (ORGANIZATION_ID, SURVEY_ID);
```

Here is an index strategy which would be used if Postgres decides to scan the `SURVEYS_ORGANIZATIONS_RELATIONSHIP` table first:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON ORGANIZATIONAL_STRUCTURE_HISTORY (ORGANIZATION_ID, SURVEY_ID,
    ORGANIZATION_RANG, ORGANIZATION_NAME, PARENT_ORGANIZATION_ID);
```

Comment: It might be good to point out a) what the difference between the two queries is, and b) that the first query had better use `EXISTS`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe The thing is, the first query could also benefit from indexing.  If the OP is asking for strategies for two separate queries, I would say the question is too broad.  I chose to answer on the second query, assuming this is what the OP plans to use moving forward.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Why in the second indexing strategy you set all columns which are used in the SQL query. Do you think that will be enough for only 2 columns `ORGANIZATION_ID`, `SURVEY_ID`?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek I am trying to _cover_ every column in the `ORGANIZATIONAL_STRUCTURE_HISTORY` table.  If we take this approach, then (in theory) Postgres can use the index alone to cover the entire query.  We could also try your approach, but Postgres might be less likely to use that index.

Comment: Thank you for your last comment. Let me ask you one last question. Could you explain why you chose the second query? Why did he seem better to you than the other one?

Comment: Well I only chose it because I sensed that _you_ thought it was better `:-)`.  That being said, the first query might behave about the same as the second if it used `WHERE EXISTS` instead of `WHERE IN`.  I personally prefer the second version.